# Is there a way to get a class template in C++ and use it to create another template?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a function in C++ that takes, as parameter, a template container and returns a container of the same type but with integers. For example, I want to write a template function that generates functions like:

```
std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<std::string>);
std::vector<int> foo(std::vector<float>);
std::list<int> foo(std::list<float>);
```

The reason is that I'm trying to write a template function in C++ that is equivalent to map in JavaScript (eg: given an array of objects and a function that transforms the object in an integer, returns an array of integers).

Is there a way of doing this in C++?

Comment: Would [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) be of use to you? It doesn't do exactly what you want (return a container), but it's the standard solution for doing `map`-like conversion.

Comment: Yeess, std::transform worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) to do this:

```
template<template<class...> class C, class T>
C<int> foo(const C<T>&);
```

When you pass `std::vector<float>` to `foo`, `C` and `T` will be deduced as `std::vector` and `float` respectively, so `C<int>` is `std::vector<int>`.

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/c7h56GGqY)

Comment: Wooooww, thank you, that worked perfectly, thank you very much. I did this way: https://godbolt.org/z/MMTx4zr8j